OpenCV rectangle detection accuracy on picture
I'm a junior developer, and for my project, I need to detect rectangles on images, specifically thumbnails from the Netflix dashboard. I'm discovering OpenCV, which seems like the best option to achieve what I want, but I'm not getting good results. Some thumbnails are not being detected, and I don't understand why. My code looks like this, and I've tested many preprocessing modifications on my image, but I got the best results with these parameters:
import cv2
import numpy as np

def nothing(x):
    pass

img = cv2.imread("./photos/photo.png")

while True:
    img_copy = img.copy()

    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img_copy, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    lower_bound = np.array([1, 0, 0])
    upper_bound = np.array([180, 255, 255])

    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_bound, upper_bound)
    kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)
    erosion = cv2.erode(mask, kernel)

    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(erosion, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    for contour in contours:
        epsilon = 0.05 * cv2.arcLength(contour, True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, epsilon, True)

        if len(approx) == 4:
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
            if w >= 100 and h >= 100:
                # Dessiner un rectangle autour du contour
                cv2.rectangle(img_copy, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    cv2.imshow("Image with Contours", img_copy)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()

unprocessed image:
enter image description here
I got this result:

The result before contour tracing (erosion) looks like this:

What confuses me even more is that I don't understand why it’s specifically the undetected images that aren't being detected.
We have tried various types of preprocessing techniques: Grayscale Conversion, Thresholding, Canny Edge.

Can you share your unprocessed image? I'd check the "aspect ratio" filter you have with if w >= 100 and h >= 100. Because, at least, the last rectangle in the first row is visually "thinner" than the rest, so it might be falling your filter. That might be the reason why the rest of the rectangles are not being detected. Consider using a true aspect ratio calculation, something like width/height.

Please post your input image before any processing (photo.png).

Try using EXTERNAL contours.  You might use more morphology close to fill in the rectangles, but use a thin vertical kernel so that you do not merge rectangles horizontally, but not so tall that you merge vertically. Make the kernel just smaller than the gaps both vertically and horizontally.

You could threshold on black using cv2.inRange(). Then you should not erode your mask, unless you need the erode to separate the rectangles. You could then use morphology close with a kernel that is just smaller than the vertical and horizontal gaps. That will fill some of the black in the white rectangles in your mask, so that they are not broken into multiple smaller regions that might be separated by your erode. Your rectangle regions need to be as filled as possible in your mask. Then you might use cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL in your contour detection.

Some of your "rectangles" may not end up with 4 corners, because they are broken up by the black regions into multiple smaller shapes. That may be where you are losing the two rectangles in your output.  Print the number of corners for each of the rectangles to check. You need to make your mask rectangles as full as possible by using morphology close.

that's a web page. web pages are scraped using the page's source code, not a screenshot of it. is someone making you solve this with computer vision as a test?

that "unprocessed image" has been resized. please provide unaltered source data.

Problem resolved, thanks to @fmw42. I used External Contour
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(closing, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

and added Close Morphology:
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

and it's working perfectly. Thanks!
